# Deprecating Zend Modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, deprecated

I'm looking for the best way of deprecating a Zend 2 Module I had used to implement a version of a system I built long time ago. Now I have to create new features for this system and I would like to use the newest version of this library on the system new components. So here is the problem, I have two modules with the same name AckCore say, and I should use both on my system. There is a php/zend/another specification of how to do it?. Maybe the only way is renaming one of them, even so, there's a naming convention to follow?. I already see some deprecations using class_alias, but something like this is possible on a namespace context?

Comment: Why can't you just replace the old module with the new one?

Comment: Replacing is too much expensive. I'm thinking on create a container folder with the name of the project and put the two versions inside it with the version of the library wrapping each and writing a autoloader exception to load the version i want on the runtime.

Comment: How about semantic versioning: develop your new module features/architecture and bump the major version number?

Comment: why not API version control send a version number in your header and in a route set if version number x send to old and if version number y send to new.

Comment: I think the way to go is, as you said user3750649, using a api style putting the version name on the namespace. AckCore\V1\... I saw this too on the apigility way of doing things.